# How to add view created in a ListAdapter to an array

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

So lets say I have an Adapter which looks like this:

```
public class CalculateListingsLVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private String[] Vars;
    private String[] VarDescriptions;
    private Activity context;
    public CalculateListingsLVAdapter(Activity context, String[] Vars, String[] Vardescs) {
        super(context, R.layout.make_calculation_lv, Vars);
        this.context = context;
        this.Vars = Vars;
        this.VarDescriptions= Vardescs;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if(convertView==null)
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.make_calculation_lv, null, true);
        TextView titleTV = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.VarTitle);
        EditText userINP = row.findViewById(R.id.VarInput);
        if (!VarDescriptions[position].equals("")) {
            String g = Vars[position] + " - " + VarDescriptions[position];
            titleTV.setText(g);
        } else {
            titleTV.setText(Vars[position]);
        }
        userINP.setTag(Vars[position]);
        return row;
    }


}
```

I want to be able to get the input from the EditTexts. Obviously something like this doesn't work:

```
        ListView calcLV = findViewById(R.id.VariablesLV);
        EditText et;
        View r;
        String curform = formula;

        for (int i = 0; i < calcLV.getCount(); i++) {
            r = calcLV.getChildAt(i);
            et =  r.findViewById(R.id.VarInput);
            String l = (String) et.getTag();
            System.out.println(l);
            String val = et.getText().toString();
            curform = curform.replace(l,val);
        }
```

Since the ListView will not show all of the items at all times.

So I tried instead to add the following code to my Adapter:

```
public ArrayList<EditText> editTxts = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then to append each userINP editText to that ArrayList to be accessed later. Unfortunately, this resulted in the  null object reference error which stated that I could not add userINP to an array

How best to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out:

Within your ArrayAdapter class, create an ArrayList to store your editText values when the edit text is edited, like this:

```
public class CalculateListingsLVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private String[] Vars;
    private String[] VarDescriptions;
    private Activity context;
    public ArrayList<String> textValues = new ArrayList<>();
    public CalculateListingsLVAdapter(Activity context, String[] Vars, String[] Vardescs) {
        super(context, R.layout.make_calculation_lv, Vars);
        this.context = context;
        this.Vars = Vars;
        this.VarDescriptions= Vardescs;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        System.out.println(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if(convertView==null)
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.make_calculation_lv, null, true);
        TextView titleTV = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.VarTitle);
        final EditText userINP = row.findViewById(R.id.VarInput);
        userINP.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit)
            {
                String g = Vars[position] + "_____" + mEdit.toString();
                for (int i = 0; i < textValues.size(); i++){
                    if (textValues.get(i).contains(Vars[position])){
                        textValues.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                textValues.add(g);
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        });
        if (!VarDescriptions[position].equals("")) {
            String g = Vars[position] + " - " + VarDescriptions[position];
            titleTV.setText(g);
        } else {
            titleTV.setText(Vars[position]);
        }

        return row;
    }


}
```

Then, in your MainActivity, you can draw from the ArrayList and use regex to get the variable and the value.